# Understanding Pointer

Tags: c, pointers, undefined-behavior, dereference, pointer-arithmetic

I have this problem and I don't understand what this means. I ask my questions in the comments.

```
int x = 3; 
int *y = &x;     

int z = *y;
printf("%d", z); //why does this give me the value and not the adress? I thought this means z =*y -> *y =&x -> &x outputs the adress of x

int *u= (y+1);  //what does this mean? 
printf("%d", *u); //why does this give the output of 3?
```

Comment: The last line is undefined behavior.

Comment: The last one should give you `Segmentation fault`. You can this out to understand pointers- https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/c-pointers. Pointers can be headache to understand, but once you understand them and know how to implement them, these will be the most fun to work with.

Comment: @user1234 That is wrong (or at least very unlikely). Segmentation faults don't automatically happen when accessing pointers in invalid ways. In practice, you're going to read some other garbage on the stack.

Answer (score 1):

Pointers store an address.
The asterisk `*y` de-references the pointer to get the value the pointer points to.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ( void) {
    int x = 3;
    int *y = NULL;
    y = &x; // store the address of x in the pointer
            // y now points to x

    printf ( "address of x:        %p\n", (void *)&x);
    printf ( "address y points to: %p\n", (void *)y);
    printf ( "address of y:        %p\n", (void *)&y);

    int z = 0;
    z = *y; //*y de-references the pointer to get the value at the address
            //stored in the pointer.

    printf ( "value y points to:   %d\n", *y);
    printf ( "value of z:          %d\n", z);

    int *w = NULL;
    w = y; // store the address y points to in the pointer w
           // w and y now point to x

    printf ( "address w points to: %p\n", (void *)w);
    printf ( "address of w:        %p\n", (void *)&w);
    printf ( "value w points to:   %d\n", *w);

    int array[6] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
    int element = 0;

    w = array; // store the address of array in w
               // w now points to array

    printf ( "address of array:    %p\n", (void *)array);
    printf ( "address w points to: %p\n", (void *)w);
    element = *w;
    printf ( "value of element:    %d\n", element);

    element = *(w + 3);
    printf ( "value of element:    %d\n", element);

    element = w[5];
    printf ( "value of element:    %d\n", element);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`y` is a pointer that points to the integer variable `x`.

```
int x = 3; 
int *y = &x;
```

So dereferencing the pointer `y` you can get a direct access to the the variable `x` pointed to by the pointer and extract its value.

Thus in this declaration

```
int z = *y;
```

the variable `z` is initialized by the value of the variable `x` by means of using the pointer `y` that points to `x`.

Correspondingly this statements

```
printf("%d", z);
```

outputs the value `3` by which the variable `z` was initialized.

In this declaration

```
int *u= (y+1);
```

in the initializing expression there is an expression with the pointer arithmetic. The expression `y + 1` has the type `int *` and points in the memory after the variable (object) `x` pointed to by the pointer `y`.

Dereferencing the pointer `u` that does not point to a valid object in this statement

```
printf("%d", *u);
```

invokes undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

```
int z = *y;
printf("%d", z);
```

**Q:** why does this give me the value and not the adress?
**A:** `y` points to the `x` variable. Therefore dereferencing the `y` pointer fives 3.`*y` is the value where `y` points to which is the value of `x` which is 3. The chapter dealing with pointers in your C text book explains it.

```
int *u= (y+1);
```

**Q:** what does this mean?
**A:** `y` points to `x` (as seen before). `y + 1` points to the `int` that is in memory right after `x`, but this is garbage, because there is nothing valid at that address, it's an invalid memory address.

```
printf("%d", *u);
```

**Q:** why does this give the output of 3?
**A:** as expained above `u` doesn't point to a valid address, therefore the value you read at that address is garbage, it could be anything. Dereferencing pointers that point to invalid memory is *undefined behavior* (google that term).